# Is there a sequence of real numbers with no subsequential limits?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm taking these definitions from Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. A subsequence of $\{ a_n\}$ is a set $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $n_k < n_{k+1}$.

If $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a subsequence of our main sequence and $lim_{k\to\infty} \{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ exists, we say this value is a *subsequential limit* of $\{a_n\}$. I'm also allowing for sequences to have $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ as limits, so these could also be subsequential limits of a sequence.

My question is: Is there a sequence of real numbers with no subsequential limits? Or is the set of subsequential limits always nonempty?

Comment: A sequence of real numbers is bounded or unbounded, so ...

Comment: Yeah just found this theorem in Rudin…”every bounded sequence in R contains a convergent subsequence”.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried constructing such a sequence? That can be quite instructive.

If I reach back far enough in my memory of my degree (all the way back to the beginning of my first year), I believe we have something called the Scenic viewpoint theorem. This theorem proves we always have either a monotonically increasing subsequence or a monotonically decreasing subsequence. Whether these are bounded or not doesn't matter for you, as you're considering the affinely extended reals, so all monotone sequences have limits.

I won't give full details, but firstly, consider the set of points of your sequence that are greater than all those that follow. If this is empty then you must have an increasing subsequence. Else, we have that these "viewpoints" that can look out to infinity without seeing any other points strictly greater than them. Now, clearly if this set of viewpoints is infinite we have a monotone decreasing subsequence. Try and reason out why this set cannot be finite, and as such we have to have a monotone decreasing subsequence.

(Note, if you're asking this you mightn't know what monotone means? A sequence is monotonically increasing each element is less than or equal to the next one. Well, at least that's the definition I was given. It might be different for you. A similar definition is used for monotonically decreasing.)

Answer (score 0):

Every set of real numbers is either bounded or unbounded. If the set ${a_n}$ is unbounded, you can construct a subsequence that converges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

If it is bounded, then it must have a limit point in $\mathbb{R}$. This is because every bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of a closed interval. Closed intervals are compact, so ${a_n}$ is a subset of a compact set, and an infinite subset E of a compact set K must have a limit point in K. (This is assuming ${a_n}$ is infinite. If it is finite, you must have an element that repeats an infinite number of times, so you can create a subsequence converging to that element.)

Finally, you can construct a subsequence that converges to each limit point of ${a_n}$. So since we know at least one limit point exists, there must be at least one subsequential limit.

Comment: Hi Jose, this is my question, I answered it myself because I found the answer a few minutes after I posted it. I don't see why this is a low quality question though--it may have a simple answer, but I don't think this is an obvious property of real sequences to someone just starting to study analysis. I also did not see any duplicate questions here, otherwise I would not have posted it.

Comment: I missed that the fact that the question is yours.

Comment: I can add more definitions to the question to make it higher quality, if that helps. Or if you find a duplicate I can close it.

Comment: It is quite clear that the question lacks context. It is likely that it will be closed.

Comment: I read the quality guide and added some definitions to provide context. Hope that helps.